# NETGEAR Router: DNS Server Not Responding

Tags: windows, dns, router

I'm running Windows 7 64-bit Professional edition and I've been using NETGEAR Router WNR612v3 for a while now. I'm not a professional in networking, but apparently the DNS server all of my computers in this house use is not responding. All the computers network card settings are set to automatic, both in resolving an IP address and resolving a DNS server.

I've had this issue all morning and fixed it by making my main computers DNS server static listening to one of GOOGLEs public DNS server (208.67.222.222) and that works perfectly. I then put my computer back to automatically resolve a DNS server and went to NETGEARs control panel by accessing my default gateway address (192.168.x.x) and configured the DNS address settings. I set it to automatically get one from my ISP (Bahnhof SE). That didn't work, so I've set it to static and tested three addresses at a time using all of these:

> 213.80.98.2
>
> 213.80.101.3
>
> 208.67.222.222
>
> 8.8.8.8
>
> 8.8.4.4

with no avail. It seems that my computers just won't resolve the DNS server given by NETGEAR, or I'm just understanding this wrong. But the end result is that my computer is obviously not receiving the Public GOOGLE DNS server that I've set on the NETGEAR DNS Addresses configuration. Here are a few screen shots:

> [Screenshot #1](http://x-riven.comule.com/img/?img=axnqgpmb5sowf1uum5cyyg)
>
> [Screenshot #2](http://x-riven.comule.com/img/?img=4szimea5clrupjobmvvk1m)
>
> [Screenshot #3](http://x-riven.comule.com/img/?img=ksvciny0oh2j1gugi2eqp0)
>
> [Screenshot #4](http://x-riven.comule.com/img/?img=etvhcp1xujjuffybq3axju)

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the limited information you provided all I can do is speculate that the firmware on your router is outdated or faulty, try updating the firmware or connect to an open Wi-fi network to ensure that the router is the problem. You will have to find where the problem is to fix it. My bet is on the router based on the fact that several computers within your house are having the same issue, and when adding the dns server address statically on the computers it works. So update the firmware, if that doesn't work go buy another router.